# how to populate the user id by where isDisliked field is false

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I need to populate the user from likedBy by where isDisliked is false, please find the document schema.[image]

I am using the query below but can't populate the users. using this below query,

```
let likedBy = await StoryComment.aggregate([{"$match":{"_id": exportLib.ObjectId(currentPost)}}, {"$match":{"comments.likedBy.isDisliked": false}}]);
```

getting the output like below,

```
[
  {
    _id: 60fd5b5336a2780754021ce0,
    comments: { reply: [], likedBy: [Array], report: [] },
    isDeleted: false,
    isArchived: false,
    storyId: 60fa45be78e0cc052760922f,
    comment: 'New to this place bro',
    userId: 60e7ce8e0812ba086dc16074,
    createdAt: 2021-07-25T12:38:43.427Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-07-25T13:46:28.728Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    isDisliked: false,
    _id: 60fd5d08ddf94d07d0da9d57,
    likedBy: 60e7ce8e0812ba086dc16074
  },
  {
    isDisliked: false,
    _id: 60fd6b34fa5bdf06a743fc3c,
    likedBy: 60df550da01794081fc83762
  }
]
```

need the user details on the place of likedBy (as we simply do with populate), this is just the de structured version of likedBy array.

Please find the schema here:

```
const storyComments = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    storyId: { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "stories" },
    comment: { type: String },
    userId: { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Users" },
    comments: {
      reply: [{
        comment: { type: String },
        userId: { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Users" },
      }],
      likedBy : [{
        likedBy: { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Users" },
        isDisliked: { type: Boolean, default: false}
      }],
      report : [{
        reportedBy: { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Users" },
        reason: { type: String },
        isReported: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        isAdminApproved: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        isCreatorApproved: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        creatorEmail: { type: String },
        tokenToApprove: { type: String, default: ""}
      }]
    },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isArchived: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Please help me to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: I have updated the question, pls find it there

Comment: Can you share your `StoryComment` schema?

Comment: Please find the schema

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to populate the users

```
const story = StoryComment.find({
          "_id": exportLib.ObjectId(currentPost),
          "comments.likedBy": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "isDisliked": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "comments.likedBy.$": 1
        })
        .populate('Users')
        .exec(function (err, person) {
                if (err) return handleError(err);
                console.log(person);
        });
```

Here is the link to the official documentation: [Ref to childeren](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#refs-to-children)

OR

If you want to do it via `aggregate` pipeline you can try out this code

```
db.story.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005")
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$comments.likedBy"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "comments.likedBy.isDisliked": false
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      likedBy: "$comments.likedBy.likedBy"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "likedBy",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "user"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$user"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$user"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the link to the playground to test your use cases: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LlzIxgxYOwl)